# Java - JPA: How can I create a table for each subclass but not for superclass?

Tags: java, inheritance, jpa, abstract-class, subclass

I have a class structure like:

```
abstract class A {
    String a;
}

class B extends A {
    String b;
}

class C extends A {
    String c;
}
```

Now I want JPA to create a table for each subclass.

[image]

I have looked some previous questions but I am confused. How can I map these classes?

Comment: Take a look at this blog post: http://uaihebert.com/?p=617

Comment: Thank you very much. Is there any way to create only tables for subclasses?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the A is inherited because of mappings and you do not need separate entity for it, you can defined it as [MappedSuperClass](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/persistence/MappedSuperclass.html). Mapped superclass is only for inheriting mappings, you cannot query it.

On the other hand if real inheritance is needed - depending about implementation - you can go for [table per (concrete) class](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/persistence/InheritanceType.html#TABLE_PER_CLASS) inheritance strategy. Support for this strategy is  optional, so it is not guaranteed to work with all implementations. It is supported at least with fresh versions of

- [Hibernate](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/annotations/reference/en/html_single/#d0e1191)
- [DataNucleus](http://www.datanucleus.org/products/datanucleus/jpa/orm/inheritance.html#tableperclass)
- [OpenJPA](http://openjpa.apache.org/builds/1.0.1/apache-openjpa-1.0.1/docs/manual/ref_guide_mapping_limits.html)
- [EclipseLink](http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/UserGuide/JPA/Basic_JPA_Development/Entities/Inheritance#Example:_Using_TABLE_PER_CLASS_with_.40Inheritance_annotation).

In your case needed step would be then to add following to the class A: `@Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)`

Comment: I have just reading about MappedSuperClass. Thank you for answer.

Answer (score 0):

Why not annotate Class A with @MappedSuperClass use Table sub class or Table for Concrete Class inhertience strategy